# Why does my flask test client fail about 60% of the time?

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I've minimized my problem to a self-contained flask app + unit test. When this is run with `pytest app.py` it fails roughly half the time (29 out of 50 runs) with this error:

```
E           werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'thing' with values ['_sa_instance_state']. Did you forget to specify values ['id']?
```

The frustrating part about this is that adding debugging statements in the `post()` method make it always pass (see comment below).

This feels like a race condition somewhere in the framework. Is SQLAlchemy spawning a thread to perform the commit and update `t.id`?

I can force it to fail by doing a `del t.id` at the site of the comment (confirming that the error is coming from a missing t.id). I can force it to pass by doing a `t.id = 999` at the same spot.

Am I doing something obviously wrong here or is this a bug in one of the packages?

I'm running python 3.5.2 and my requirements.txt is:

```
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.6
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Jinja2==2.10
pytest==3.2.2
pytest-repeat==0.4.1
SQLAlchemy==1.2.8
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

It may be worth noting that this also failed with earlier versions of most of these packages (flask 0.12, sqlalchemy 1.1.14, etc).

It may also be worth noting that when run with `pytest --count=20 app.py` it will always pass or fail the entire count, i.e. 20 passes or 20 failures. But about half the overall runs will still fail.

Here's the app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, fields, marshal, reqparse
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import pytest

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Thing(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)

thing_fields = {
    'name': fields.String,
    'uri': fields.Url('thing'),
}

class ThingListAPI(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument('name', type=str, location='json')
        super().__init__()

    def post(self):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
        t = Thing(name=args['name'])
        db.session.add(t)
        db.session.commit()
        ### <<< at this point inserting pretty much any statement
        ###     will make the test pass >>>
        return {'thing': marshal(t, thing_fields)}, 201

class ThingAPI(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        pass

api.add_resource(ThingListAPI, '/things', endpoint='things')
api.add_resource(ThingAPI, '/things/<int:id>', endpoint='thing')

@pytest.fixture
def stub_app():
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
    client = app.test_client()
    db.create_all()
    yield client
    db.drop_all()

def test_thing_post(stub_app):
    resp = stub_app.post('/things', data=json.dumps({'name': 'stuff'}),
                         content_type='application/json')
    assert(resp.status_code == 201)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `db.session.refresh(t)` in `post()` after commit, it will solve the problem. I don't know whether it's a right thing to do so (SQLAlchemy is quite complicated and I had a little experience with it), but it shows that a `t`-object state sometimes is not refreshed (*sometimes* because probably there is a race condition and sometimes SQLAlchemy *maybe* gets more machine time and pulls id just in time, but sometimes is not) after a commit and `id`-attribute still somehow doesn't exist (I mean, for *flask*, because for sqlite it does exist, but a new state is not pulled from a DB).